# Hashing-algorithm for dates

Tags: algorithm, hash, date

What would be a good hash-algorithm to hash dates, e.g. 24/12/09 and 31/10/89?

The dates would range from about year 1950 to 2050.

Could using the unix timestamp somehow, be possible?

Comment: Well yes, you can use the UNIX timestamp as there's guaranteed to be a unique one every second. I could answer better if you enlightened us on why you're hashing.

Comment: I want to store pairs of dates and then check if excactly that pair has been entered before.

Comment: @stereofrog, depending on the implementation of the hash, the above would require an allocation of an 20,501,231 sized array, which is quite huge.

Comment: @cvondrick, in that case I'd rather use binary insertion and sorting. My problem now, is however how I can combine two dates to one number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the number of days instead of the number of seconds since the start of the Unix Epoch. Just calculate:

```
<unix timestamp> / 86400
```

Comment: are you sure that % is good operation, i would prefer divison.

Comment: @ralu: You’re right, it must be division and not modulo since I’m interested in the full days an not the remaining seconds.

Comment: This is fine but it won't address the OP needs: "I want to store pairs of dates and then check if **exactly that pair** has been entered before".